# flexbox flex-direction:column with textarea not working as expected in Firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The following example works as expected in Chrome but not in Firefox.

The footer height is set to `height:40px` and in Chrome is ok, however in Firefox is smaller, around `35px` . Any reasons why?

https://jsfiddle.net/47gg3fdc/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="textarea">
    <textarea placeholder="textarea ..."></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    #footer
  </div>
</div>

.container{
  display:flex;
  height:100px;
  background-color:whitesmoke;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.textarea{
  flex-grow:1;
  display:flex;
}

.footer{
  background-color:lightseagreen;
  height:40px;
  color:white;
}

textarea{
   flex-grow: 1;
   border: none;
   resize: none;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 16px;
   margin: 0px;
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: I think with flex it can take flex-basis into account so sometimes may resize certain elements - I have always found that I have to add min-height and max-heights in if I want it to respect those measurements in all browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that Firefox find the `textarea` somewhat higher than Chrome does, and as such, there is no space for the `footer`.

And the reason it does, is simply that `form` elements have predefined size and that size often differs between the browsers.

So what happens here is that Firefox adjust the flex items and make them shrink a little to fit their parent, though as the `<textarea>` is not a flex item, but flex item *content*, and its parent, the `.textarea` *div* element isn't allowed to [shrink past content size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size), it is the `footer` that will shrink.

---

If one add `flex-shrink: 0` to the `footer`, which will disallow it to shrink, it will have the same height in both browsers.

*To test this, change e.g. the `padding: 5px` to `padding: 0`, and the `footer` will have the same height in both browsers.*

Stack snippet

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  height:100px;
  background-color:whitesmoke;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.textarea{
  flex-grow:1;
  display:flex;
}

.footer{
  background-color:lightseagreen;
  height:40px;
  color:white;
  flex-shrink: 0;                  /*  added  */
}

textarea{
   flex-grow: 1;
   border: none;
   resize: none;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 16px;
   margin: 0px;
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="textarea">
    <textarea placeholder="textarea ..."></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    #footer
  </div>
</div>
```